# Echinopsis multiplex is getting brown and soft in the bottom. It also has developed a hairy growth on one side

Tags: plant-care, cactus

[image]

I have been watering the cactus once a week. The bottom has got really soft and mushy.
The cactus also has hairy growth on the top for a month.

Update: You are right, the growth was a flower. And it was really beautiful. Rot still exists
[image: cactus in flower]

Comment: Aiii! The brown soft part is rot! It is lethal, and it doesn't seem you can easily cut it off somehow... The hairy stuff is a new flower by the way, hope it will still develop.

Comment: Ya, you are right, the growth was a flower. And it was really beautiful.
Rot still exists :(